# Browser not picking latest code after appending versioning also?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-cache

Client browser not picking the latest **html** changes after i pushed some changes to prod.

I am using grunt to build my code and its appending some random numbers to my files also.

**Example:** scripts.7c7e7b63.js, vendor.4555d658.js

**But still client browser not picking those changes.**

Here is the screenshot
[image]

So the only solution i am finding is to tell users to clear their browser cache manually. So thy can see the latest changes.

But its feel so wrong to tell users every-time to clear browser cache.

Is there any permanent solution for this.

Comment: Are you running any grunt cache busting task like `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-asset-cachebuster');`

Comment: Perhaps it is because your `max-age` is still valid, you might need to check your assets header in the `network` panel of your dev tools, you might want to know more about caching: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: @Senal no i am not.

Comment: @t3__rry I checked but in my network there is not max-age, i just added the screenshot in my question. You can check there.

Comment: @AkshayKumar Are you using any CDN to cache your assets? Perhaps you would need to flush them for your changes to be reflected

Comment: @t3__rry no we are not using any CDN

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I face but Below is an example which solve for me

> 1. src="scripts?v1.7c7e7b63.js
> 2. src="vendor?v1.4555d658.js